# Como usar o emit e computed/watch

Tags: laravel, vue.js, momentjs

sou novo com VueJS e comecei a desenvolver um projeto para estudo de um planilha de lançamento de horas e cálculo de horas trabalhadas.

Estou utilizando no projeto Laravel 5.5 com Vuejs 2 e MomentJS para calcular as diferenças.

Porém não consegui entender como utilizar o emit para enviar para fora dos meu component filho para o pai os dados atualizados e nem como fazer o campo `Trabalhado` ser atualizado sozinho com o cálculo de `moment(moment(this.entrada_1,"hh:mm").diff(moment(this.saida_1,"hh:mm"))).format("hh:mm");` (inicialmente apenas a primeira diferença para poder aprender e depois tentar calcular o resto.

[image: Tabela de Exemplo]
Acima está o modelo da tabela que estou desenvolvendo e abaixo os códigos blade e o json

```
// blade.php
<vue-appointment :timetable="{{ $timetable }}"></vue-appointment>
<!-- timetable é o objeto abaixo -->

// jsonObject
{
   days: [
     { numero: 1, nome: "QUI", entrada_1: "00:00:00", saida_1: "00:00:00", trabalhado: "00:00:00" //...},
     { numero: 2, nome: "SEX", entrada_1: "00:00:00", saida_1: "00:00:00", trabalhado: "00:00:00" //...}
     { numero: 3, nome: "SÁB", entrada_1: "00:00:00", saida_1: "00:00:00", trabalhado: "00:00:00" //...}
   ]
}
```

Abaixo o example dos meus 2 components VueJS.

Apointment.vue

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20px">#</th>
                        <th width="20px" class="text-center">Dia</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Trabalhado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <vue-appointment-row v-for="day in timetable.days" :key="day.virtual_id" :day=day></vue-appointment-row>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {TheMask} from 'vue-the-mask'
import { Moment } from 'moment'

export default {

    props: ['timetable', 'old'],

    components: { TheMask },

    data () {
        return {
            object: {}
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        console.log(this.timetable);
    },

    methods: {

    },

    computed: {
    }

}
</script>
```

AppointmentRow.vue

```
<template>
<tr>
    <td>{{ day.numero }}</td>
    <td>{{ day.nome }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_1]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_1"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_1]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_1"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_2]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_2"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_2]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_2"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_3]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_3"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_3]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_3"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_4]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_4"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_4]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_4"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][trabalhado]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.trabalhado"></the-mask></td>
</tr>
</template>

<script>
import {TheMask} from 'vue-the-mask'
import { Moment } from 'moment'

export default {

    props: ['day'],

    components: { TheMask },

    data () {
        return {
            object: {}
        }
    },

    mounted() {
    },

    methods: {
    },

    computed: {}

}
</script>
```

Uma explicação de como usar o computed/watch nessa situação para atualizar o trabalhado conforme for editando a linha, me ajudaria a entender melhor como funciona este processo do computed/watch.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, neste caso em minha opinião a melhor abordagem é utilizando o [sync Modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

Basicamente, para você transmitir o valor que está sendo digitado no componente "filho", no caso o `AppointmentRow.vue`, para o componente "pai", o `Appointment.vue`, você pode simplemente colocar o sufixo `.sync` em usa prop `day`.

Em seguida, dentro do componente `AppointmentRow.vue`, você cria um [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) nesta prop, onde irá emitir o valor que está sendo digitado para o pai, segue abaixo:

```
watch: {
  day (newValue) {
    this.$emit('update:day', newValue)
  }
}
```

Em cada alteração do valor `day`, o `watch` será executado. Cada alteração do valor *pode* ser recebido por parâmetro. Por sua vez, está sendo emitido o valor digitado de cada atributo alterado para o componente "pai".

Realizei seu exemplo assim:

**Appointment.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th width="20px">#</th>
                          <th width="20px" class="text-center">Dia</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Entrada</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Saída</th>
                          <th class="text-center">Trabalhado</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="day in days" :key="day.virtual_id">
                      <appointment-row :day.sync="day">                      
                      </appointment-row>
                      p {{ day }}
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AppointmentRow from './AppointmentRow'

  export default {
    props: ['timetable', 'old'],
    components: { AppointmentRow },
    data () {
      return {
        days: [
          { numero: 1, nome: 'QUI', entrada_1: '00:00:00', saida_1: '00:00:00', trabalhado: '00:00:00' },
          { numero: 2, nome: 'SEX', entrada_1: '00:00:00', saida_1: '00:00:00', trabalhado: '00:00:00' },
          { numero: 3, nome: 'SÁB', entrada_1: '00:00:00', saida_1: '00:00:00', trabalhado: '00:00:00' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**AppointmentRow.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <td>{{ day.numero }}</td>
    <td>{{ day.nome }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_1]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_1"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_1]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_1"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_2]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_2"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_2]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_2"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_3]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_3"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_3]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_3"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][entrada_4]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.entrada_4"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][saida_4]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.saida_4"></the-mask></td>
    <td class="text-center"><the-mask class="form-control" :mask="['##:##']" :name="'days['+day.numero+'][trabalhado]'" :masked="true" required v-model="day.trabalhado"></the-mask></td>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { TheMask } from 'vue-the-mask'

  export default {
    props: ['day'],
    components: { TheMask },
    watch: {
      day (newValue) {
        this.$emit('update:day', newValue)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

No parágrafo `p {{ day }}` pode ser verificado a alteração do valor, cada vez que está sendo digitado dentro do componente filho.

Outra forma de realizar isto, sem a utilização do `sync Modifier`, é utilizando um `v-model` ao invés da prop `day`:

```
<appointment-row v-model="day"></appointment-row>
```

Dentro do `AppointmentRow.vue` você realiza a troca de `day` para `value` em todo o código:

```
props: ['value'],
```

E altere o `$emit` do `watch`:

```
this.$emit('input', newValue)
```

O funcionamento será o mesmo, no entanto se futuramente desejar passar mais uma prop, e o valor desta prop deverá ser transmitido para o pai, não há como utilizar com o `v-model`, apenas com o `sync Modifier`.